# How to execute .bat file in PHP from remote server?

Tags: php, batch-file, remote-server

I am trying to execute following code in PHP. It runs, but returns the result of my local system, where I need the bat file should run on remote system.

```
if( pclose(popen("cmd /c "."\\\\ServerName\path\Test.bat", 'r')) ) {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Test.bat
DIR > mohit.txt
 and I see mohit.txt is created in my local machine root directory, where as I was expecting to have the file on remote server in same directory.

Comment: Where did you run the PHP script? On your local development system? Because there is no way whatsoever that a PHP script running on a remote server is able to run a batch file on your local machine. Or rather, if it were possible PHP would have a much worse security track record than it already has.

Comment: With above command, you should run the remote file just fine. You are however still on your local machine in your local dir. You just executed a remote batch file on your local system.

It's not a problem with PHP, it would react all the sam if you opened a console locally and executed above remote batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using php's [exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) function?

`exec( '/path/Test.bat' );`